# What happens if we double the slit width of just one slit, in Young's double slit experiment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, waves, double-slit-experiment, quantum-optics

If the width of one slit is doubled, but that it is still much narrower than the distance to the screen, what happens to the intensity distribution that we see on the screen?

I have been reading some sources that state where we had minima, are no longer of $0$ intensity (i.e. destructive interference) but are just $1/9^{th}$ of the maximum intensity.

I had one idea why this might be the case, but I don't know if it's "mathematically rigorous" or even right. Since we know that the intensity is proportional to area of slit, and the areas are in ratio of 1:2, then we can say that the amplitudes is in a ratio of $1:\sqrt{2}$ (since amplitudes are the square root of intensity more or less). At the maxima, the 2 waves get added, so the maxima will be $1+\sqrt{2}$ whereas at the minima the amplitudes  will be $1-\sqrt{2}$, so the intensities would be of a ratio $\frac{(1-\sqrt{2})^{2}}{(1+\sqrt{2})^2}$ which isn't 1/9.

I am trying to formulate a mathematical description/proof of this but can't. Any guidance is much appreciated.

EDIT: could it be perhaps that slit width is not proportional to intensity, and is in fact proportional to amplitude?

Comment: Which 'sources'? If you provide that context then it will be easier to answer.

Comment: It was a question from a physics textbook. I can post the picture but I don't think it's much help.

Comment: Maybe don't include the image into the post, but do include a link to the image as well as a complete reference to the textbook. Context *always* helps.

Comment: Well, what is the Fourier transform of the new slit configuration?

Comment: I don't really know much about Fourier transforms, not in the case of slits anyway.

Comment: "could it be perhaps that slit width is not proportional to intensity, and is in fact proportional to slit width?" Do you mean proportional to amplitude?

Comment: Oops, yeah sorry I meant amplitude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First consider the two slits alone, than open the second half of one slit. The interference of the two equal slits remains. However, the third which contributes 1/3 of the amplitude gives, at the place of the minimum, almost a maximum, though it will be a little less than 1/9 of the intensity since there is some negative interference of the half slit.

Comment: Hmm I suppose. But to give it some mathematical treatment, would one just perform a  Kirchhoff Diffraction Integral?

Comment: I would use Huygens–Fresnel since I am not familiar with Kirchhoff Diffraction Integral